# Network Load Balancer Listeners and VPC connection relationship

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

When you add listeners to a NLB, you specify port and protocols only. Let's say I create a VPC connection to a NLB, of which I have a bunch of different listeners. In the API Gateway integration request I now put in a request using this VPC link, and specify an `Endpoint URL` of: `http://foobar:yolo/api`.

Is the host of `foobar` actually used or could I write anything there? As it is only the `http` protocol and the `yolo` port which routes the request to the listener. Is the host still important? Or is the host only used if your endpoint would understand `tcp` and therefore read the host in the request?

Comment: You are asking about REST or HTTP API?

Comment: Both. I want to know the difference between the two interms of VPC connections from an API Gateway.

Comment: " I now put in a request using this VPC link" -  you mean value of `Secure server name - optional` in HTTP API?

Comment: When you create a VPC link in API GW, you have 2 options, I want to know what is the difference between the two. And. why when you use an NLB, whose listeners only depend on the port and protocol, do you need to specify a URL which includes a host, which is not used in the LB listener routing logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the host of foobar actually used or could I write anything there?

**Yes, it is used**, and you can't write anything. API gateway is going to send your request to the `Endpoint URL` you are going to specify. If you specify `http://foobar.com/api` your requests will fail. They will only succeed if you actually own a domain `foobar.com` that is associated with your NLB.

Thus, if you don't have a domain, you have to use default `DNS name` provided for your NLB by AWS:, e.g.:

```
http://yyyy-fd434e91.elb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
```

In contrast, if you own a domain `foobar.com` and you want to use `http` you are going to use:

```
http://foobar.com
```

If you want `HTTPS`, and have proper SSL certificate deployed on the NLB along with TLS listener, then you can write:

```
https://foobar.com
```

In addition, **your application behind the NLB** is going to receive the host from `Endpoint URL` in a request from the API in a `Host` header, e.g.:'

```
Host: yyyy-fd434e91.elb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
```